# General recommendations for C# MVC Entity Framework 6 database context and connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ado.net

Are there any general recommendations for handling multiple users and connections with Entity Framework and MVC in C# for how many database connections (ADO.NET models and contexts) should be?

For example, I have multiple database users which have different CRUD permissions in the database. Currently I'm using only 1 ADO.NET model of the database (therefore always the same context) which has all CRUD permissions enabled, but should I use multiple ADO.NET models (multiple contexts) and if yes, are there any guidelines for this? General rules of a thumb? I haven't been able to locate this across the internet, so any help from experienced developers is highly appreciated.

Comment: The same as always. Don't try to do it yourself. Open the connection/DbContext inside a `using` block, don't keep it for long, don't use long running transactions. Definitely don't keep a connection/transaction open for the duration of a request. The *DbContext* will open and close a connection by itself when reading, and do so again to persist all changes when you call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: A *model* isn't a *context*. A *context* isn't a *connection*. ADO.NET uses connection pooling to reset and reuse connections from the server so you *don't* need to keep connections open for long. Reopening a connection costs *nothing*. Keeping it open for long though gathers locks and leads to *blocking* between connections. You could serve 10K users with just 10 connections if you use pooling. You couldn't even serve 10 users if you keep connections and transactions open for long and read lots of redundant data from the same table

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for model-context-connection clarification :) so do I have to care about database users and their CRUD permissions that I set in SQL Management Studio?